# is possible to create form element in view same as in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

1st way to creating form elements like below -

*In Controller

```
    $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');

    $email->setLabel('Email address')

          ->addFilter('StringToLower')

          ->setRequired(true)

          ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)

          ->addValidator('EmailAddress');
```

2nd way to creating form elements like below -

*In View

```
echo $this->formText('email',$this->data['email'],array('size'=>'20', 'class'=>'input_min_max'));
```

Is there possible to create element in 2nd method with same as in 1st method, Like adding addFilter,addValidator etc. .  setLabel is not required becoz we have added the label just before the element ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can execute this code in the view :

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$email->setLabel('Email address')
      ->addFilter('StringToLower')
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
      ->addValidator('EmailAddress');
```

But you **shouldn't** because it's violating the MVC pattern.
Or maybe you could explain better what you want to do... maybe I didn't understand...

Answer (score 0):

I' pretty sure you cannot create an element with your second method, but there is another way to create it by factoring, in your case you can do :

```
$formText = createElement('email',$this->data['email'],array('size'=>'20', 'class'=>'input_min_max)->setRequired(true)->addValidator('whatever');
```

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Is there any error in this line of code `echo $formText = 
$this->createElement('text','bajrang.lal@gmail.com',array('size'=>'20', 'class'=>'input_min_max'))
->setRequired(true)
->addValidator('EmailAddress');`

Comment: What is 'bajrang.lal@gmail.com' ? if i understand, you want this to be the label or the value of the email object no ? if it is you should put it in the array like 'value' => 'bajrang.lal@gmail.com' or 'label' => 'bajrang.lal@gmail.com' have i made my point ?

Comment: Ohh sorry its the name of control replace with 'email' to 'bajrang.lal@gmail.com'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to insert the form element in the view. If this is for styling, you can use a view script as the decorator.

The form :

```
 $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');

 $email->setLabel('Email address')

      ->addFilter('StringToLower')

      ->setRequired(true)

      ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
      -> setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'index/myform.phtml'))))

      ->addValidator('EmailAddress');
```

This will call the view script "myform.phtml" for decorating the element, inside which you can add the rest of the markup for decorating the element.